# Sync IE favorites on Vista

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, internet-explorer, sync, bookmarks

How do I sync IE favorites (and preferably RSS feeds) between two computers running Windows 7 and Vista?

I’d like to avoid companies with questionable privacy policies (like Google).

The computers are on the same network most of the time.

Comment: Clarification: By “questionable privacy policy” I mean selling potentially identifiable information to third parties.

Comment: Any file syncing solution should suffice. IE favourites are stored in `%UserProfile%\Favorites`, and the RSS feeds are in `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Feeds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the `%USERPROFILE%\Favorites` and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Feeds` folders to SkyDrive and made junctions in their old locations.